# Read data from JSON with multiple JSON objects in order to be displayed

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, json

I have the following JSON object that contains multiple JSON objects.

[image: JSON Screenshot]

I want to read and display the following elements 1) CampaignName 2) Start date 3) End date

I have written the following the following code which produces error to the browser console. So, the items are not displayed.

[image: Code that I wrote]

the produced error at the browser console is:

[image: error]

I assume I do not access the elements as appropriate.

How shall I do it ?

Comment: Please never post code in images.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I do not see any reason that code in images are not acceptable. However, please have in mind that if i copy paste all that code there will be spaces and it takes time to format them as appropriate.

Comment: Please the accessibility of written code above the time it takes to format. The first is a necessity, the second is an inconvenience.

Comment: please for this code, no need of accessibility is needed.

Comment: I don’t mean to be rude, but the question should be accessible. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question Accessibility should never be a second thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `.each` function that iterate over each object... each object has the properties that you need. Each of these values you are iterating over is an object and not an array

Use `v.Campaign.CampaignName` instead of accessing the index first

Comment: Yes, correct. it was that easy and I made it difficult onto my mind. what confused me was that in order to access that multiple JSON objects I had to handle them similarity to an array.

Let's say that the iteration starts it finds the first JSON object and one of the elements contains another JSON object. How could I modify the current code that I have written in order to access the second JSON object ?

Comment: @noruk as long as they are objects and not arrays, you can use the dot to access the elements, like the example I gave above. Campaign is a json object that has properties but if one of the properties had another json object. You would simply access it by `v.Campain.anotherJsonObject.Property`

Comment: My first belief was that somehow  I should do another loop. However, I think what you said (`v.Campain.anotherJsonObject.Property`) is reasonable and valid comparing what I thought.

Comment: Hi again. instead of using foreach how could it be done using for loop?

Answer (score 0):

the `v` that you are trying to access already is the date on a single JSON object so there is no need of passing the `count` param. I would suggest you refactoring your code to something like:

```
data.forEach(({ Campaign: {CampaignName, StartDate, EndDate } }) => {
    events.push({
       title: CampaignName,
       title: moment(StartDate),
       title: moment(EndDate),
    })
})
```

Comment: Thank you Gabriel for your support and for providing an answer. However, I have just removed the `count` param and worked.